# Python - create custom bins defined with x and y boundaries

Tags: python, pandas, bin, binning

I would like to create spatial bins like (for example) the ones in this plot here:

[image]

Here there are 412 bins but this can vary depending on how many I want (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.04701.pdf).  I have already computed all the boundary lines that defines these bins.  If I have millions of points defined by their x, y coordinates, how would I efficiently put them in one of these 412 bins.

[update]
The latitude bins are always equivalent in size while the longitudinal bins are not.  I can use np.digitize to find the latitudinal bin pretty easily, once that's found I know the bins of the longitude as well.  However I'm not sure I can vectorize np.digitize to have a different bin array for each point I provide. `longitudinal_bins_arr` would be an array of all the longitudinal bins for each latitude for the length of all the points that I'm trying to bin.

```py
lat_bin_for_points = np.digitize( latlon[:,0], latitudinal_bins )
lon_bin_for_points = np.digitize( latlon[:,1], longitudinal_bins_arr[lat_bin_for_points] )
```

Comment: Have you look at [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)? If the latitudinal steps are the same (looks like it from the figure), you just have a 1D array of bins for longitude, and it looks like they're repeated (mirrored) around y=0 (equator). `pd.cut()` requires a 1D array.